# Is laravel 5 is the stable release to start work on new project

Tags: laravel

I knew that so many have asked this question.But I have requirement before stepping into it.I just want to confirm whether I can start or not in laravel 5.0

Iam Creating a new project where I have video uploading,audio uploading,payment integration etc..

I just want to confirm whether I can do them with laravel 5.0 In the web I dont find much info for the laravel5.0

Answer (score 1):

laravel 5.0 is a stable version, and it is much better than 4.2 in its structure. especially it has native namespace support .  I think you should start with L5.

You can easily find a tutoial on laracast.com

Comment: Ok Thankyou so much @Tim.You gave me the confidence to go head.and the site which you have provided is commercial to learn.Can you provide me a nice tutorial for installing and starting with laravel in ubuntu 12.04 ?

Comment: @Choco [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0), Composer is the best way to install laravel, [video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals)

Answer (score 0):

Yes laravel 5.0 is stable release, and its much better than its old version, but if you want to use packages for your application, please checkout that packages  support laravel 5.

Comment: do we have support for 5.0?

Comment: yes we have support for Laravel 5.0 but with laravel we may need packages(bundles) to provide extra functionality to our application i.e for using mongoDB with laravel we need https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb packages, likewise for other